# Paypal : Chained Adaptive Payments

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

The reason i am asking paypal question here is that being a new user,i have not been able to post question on paypal's community/technical/ developer websites.

I have developed a website (similar to ebay) where sellers/merchants can sell their products . My websites requires a payment gateway that could take orders from normal customers who buy sellers' products, deduct commission from that ordered amount and send money to seller's bank account.
Please note that there could be 1000s of sellers to sell their products.
To achieve this, I think adaptive chained payment method suits me to serve this purpose.

**My question is:**

1- My website acting as a primary receiver, can I change secondary reciever in each API call so that I could deduct commission from orders and put the rest of money into individual seller's PayPal account?

2- How can I set up my PayPal account to receive chain adaptive payments?What is the procedure to set it up as it is now a limited release product? It is now restricted to select partners for approved use cases and should not be used for new integrations without guidance from PayPal.

Here is what I tried:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/?mark=adaptive%20payment

I couldn't find the link to choose/set up Paypal chain adaptive payment.
Please accept my apology in advance as i am struggling for hours.

I would appreciate if you could share a link or guide.

Thanks